# shift rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

Table:

```
ID  Subject
1   Math
1   Eng
2   Sci
2   Phy
2   bio
```

Output:

```
id  Subject1    Subject2    Subject3
1   Math        Eng 
2   Sci         Phy         bio
```

Required output is as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with conditional aggregate  function

```
SELECT ID,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN SUBJECT END) Subject1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN SUBJECT END) Subject2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN SUBJECT END) Subject3    
FROM(
    SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ROWNUM) rn
    FROM T t1
) t1 
GROUP BY ID
```

https://rextester.com/TMGK34943

Answer (score 0):

https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot#transpose

NOC  ATH  GYM  CYC  BOX  SAI
BRA  1    3    0    1    2
CHN  6    2    2    4    1
DEN  1    0    2    0    3
ESP  2    0    0    0    0
ETH  8    0    0    0    0
GRE  1    1    0    0    2

select * from olympic_country_sport_medals 
unpivot ( 
  (medals) for sport in ( ath, box, gym, sai, cyc ) 
) 
pivot  ( 
  sum(medals) for noc in ( 
    'BRA' BRA, 'CHN' CHN, 'DEN' DEN, 'ESP' ESP, 'ETH' ETH, 'GRE' GRE
  ) 
);

Output:

SPORT          BRA  CHN  DEN  ESP  ETH  GRE
Athletics      1    6    1    2    8    1
Artistic Gym   3    2    0    0    0    1
Boxing         1    4    0    0    0    0
Sailing        2    1    3    0    0    2
Track Cycling  0    2    2    0    0    0